# Load in array txt files name to process in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to load all the `*.txt` inside a folder (or any other file) into an an array?

Because I need to do a lot of plots, each one having an input a different text file. So I was thinking that if I have a single array with all the name files, I could use a `for cycle` creating all the images at once and save it.

Is it possible?
For the moment I do this by hand, changing the name file

```
T = readtable('file.txt');
```

do some process and save it `saveas(gcf,'File.png');`

Comment: What about `files=dir("*.txt")` ? `files` is then a struct array you can iterate over

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks! Is it possible in extract also just the name, without the extension? In this way I can use the same array to save the png image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all text files in a folder with

```
d = dir( '*.txt' );
```

Then loop over them, doing something, then saving with the same name

```
for ii = 1:numel(d)
   [~,filename] = fileparts( d(ii).name );
   T = readtable( d(ii).name);
   % do stuff...
   saveas( gcf, [filename, '.png'] );   
end
```

If your current working directory isn't where the text files are, then you can use something similar but with full file paths (probably more robust regardless):

```
d = dir( 'C:\Documents\MyStuff\*.txt' );
for ii = 1:numel(d)
   [~,filename] = fileparts( d(ii).name );
   T = readtable( fullfile( d(ii).folder, d(ii).name );
   % do stuff...
   saveas( gcf, fullfile( d(ii).folder, [filename, '.png'] ) );   
end
```